# Query EC2 instance type attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

Is there a way to get the number of cores and amount of memory of an instance type from the command line `aws` tool?

Basically I want to access the data on http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ programmatically.

Comment: A similar request was asked of aws-cli and there wasn't much progress either, but there are some tips there that may be helpful: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1279

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120348/boto3-aws-api-listing-available-instance-types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not officially. But the incredible Mitch Garnaat [has a Github repository with "missingcloud" bits](https://github.com/garnaat/missingcloud). On that list is instance information. You can pick that out with your favorite language. Here's an example with a bit of `jq`. (this is imperfect, maybe someone can help split these into instance:ramMB rows?)

```
$ curl --silent https://raw.githubusercontent.com/garnaat/missingcloud/master/aws.json | jq '[.services."Elastic Compute Cloud".instance_types|to_entries|.[]|.key,.value.ramMB]' | head -9
[
  "c1.medium",
  1700,
  "c1.xlarge",
  7000,
  "c3.2xlarge",
  15000,
  "c3.4xlarge",
  30000,
```

Comment: Unfortunately that project seems to be abandoned. The information is out of date and pull requests containing updates are sitting there from last year... It would be a good starting point for a fork anyhow.