# AWS EC2 instance resize

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to resize an AWS EC2 instance using the REST API. Sometimes I get an "InvalidInstanceType" error for compatibility issues between the current and the new instance type. Is there an API using which I can find out to which all instance types this EC2 instance can be resized to ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the instance types you were trying to convert between, when the error occurred?

Comment: The issue seems very likely to be related to virtualization type.  Can you provide a specific example of a combination of new ans old type that throw the error in question?  I have an idea...

Answer (score 2):

There is no API call available to list available instance types, nor instance types that can be resized between each other.

Some people have **cobbled-together methods to list instance types:**

- [Can I get a list of instance types from aws cli?](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1279)
- [boto3 aws api - Listing available instance types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33120348/174777)
- It can also be extracted from the [AWS PriceList API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-price-list-api-update-regional-price-lists/)

However, none of these methods would include information about permitted instance types to switch between.

You can always resize an Amazon EC2 instance within the same [instance family](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/), but you might experience problems if you try to convert instances between virtualization types. See: [Amazon Linux AMI Instance Type Matrix](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/instance-type-matrix/).

The `InvalidInstanceType` error you encountered is mentioned on the [EC2 Errors documentation page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/errors-overview.html), saying:

> The instance type is not supported for this request. For example, you can only bundle instance store-backed Windows instances.

This is referring to instances with [Instance Store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html), which is storage directly attached to the instance, which is lost when the instance is stopped/terminated. This could occur when trying to start an instance with an **Instance Store-backed AMI** (which boots from Instance Store rather than EBS) when the Instance Type does not have Instance Store, but it seems strange that you would encounter this error when trying to change the Instance Type of an existing instance.

Comment: But isn't there any way to find that using an API to which instance type I am allowed to resize to. Azure provides a mechanism to do so. So I was hoping even the aws does. The AWS console has a dropdown of  allowed Instance Types when changing a VM instance type. Is that exposed via an API ?

Comment: No, there isn't. I've added some references.